# Adding custom configuration section to existing tab

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, system.xml

## Synopsis

I have created a basic local module that is designed to listen to an observer , which it does perfectly fine.  However I wish the observer method to pull out some configured settings which changes the behaviour of it's task.

I want to add a new section under the `Catalog` tab; I found [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/add-system-configuration-to-existing-tab).

I do **not** want to create a *new* tab, instead I **do** want a new *section* under the existing *Catalog* tab (similarly to *Catalog* > *Inventory*).

### Current behaviour

Currently inside the control panel I click `Catalog > Catalog`, low and behold inside this tab is a group called **Section Name Under Catalog Tab**. I also don't see my group **Group Name**.

- [Image example #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47QKp.png)
- [Image example #2](https://i.imgur.com/HVrx2dq)

### Expected behaviour

<strike>I click `Catalog > Section Name Under Catalog Tab`, inside this tab is a group called **Group Name** with my enable/disable field.</strike>

- As per Image example 1 - I'd expect a section called *Section Name Under Catalog Tab*;
- As per Image example 2 - I'd expect this to expand into a view with my group *Group Name*;
- Finally the group should contain the form present in Image exmaple 2.

## Code snippets

**local/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                                        <title>Section inside Catalog</title>
                                    </mymodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**local/Vendor/Module/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <mymodule translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>Section Name Under Catalog Tab</label>
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <category_options translate="label">
                    <label>Group Name</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                    </fields>
                </category_options>
            </groups>
        </mymodule>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what you see? I'm kind of slow today and I don't really understand the result you are getting.

Comment: I've updated the question with additional resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Conclusion

I've solved this and there were a couple of confusing aspects.  Some of the XML tag names were incorrect and the *module* reference too was invalid.

In case someone else gets the same issue, I will wrap this up.

**app/etc/modules/Myvendor_Mymodule.xml** contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myvendor_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <!-- Added this dependency to ensure it's loaded first -->
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Myvendor_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**code/local/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/config.xml** contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myvendor_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Myvendor_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <myvendor_mymodule>
                <class>Myvendor_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </myvendor_mymodule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <myvendor_mymodule>
                <class>Myvendor_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </myvendor_mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**local/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/system.xml** contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <sections>

        <!-- I don't know if this is necessary but prefixed with the parent name -->

        <catalog_mymodule translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>My Section (inside Catalog)</label>

            <!-- appears to define the catalog tab as the parent -->
            <tab>catalog</tab>

            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>

                <!-- This group should appear inside it's own space. -->

                <mymoule_group translate="label">
                    <label>Group Name</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                    </fields>
                </mymoule_group>
            </groups>
        </catalog_mymodule>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**local/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/adminhtml.xml** contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>

                                    <catalog_mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                                        <title>ACL Name for my section</title>
                                    </catalog_mymodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: should each secton with `module="mymodule"` not be `module="myvendor_mymodule"`

Comment: I think it should be, however when I tried using that it never worked and the module was valid.

Comment: Just FYI: `catalog_mymodule` prefixing with catalog doesn't matter.

Comment: module="myvendor_mymodule"    is name of helper