# 404 after trying to add new section in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have tried to add a new module `(cron job only)` with a new configuration section in the `Magento-admin`. The new section appears in the menu under the correct tab. I can change its position by modifying the sort order in the xml. I can even modify its label. I receive `404 error` whenever I click on it.

I have compared our existing code and also considered [Adding custom configuration section to existing tab](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/adding-custom-configuration-section-to-existing-tab)

What did I forget?

I have listed my configuration below.

`app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModuleName.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <MyCompany_Content />
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_MyModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModuleName/etc/system.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <mycompany_sectionname translate="label">
            <label>My Section Label</label>
            <tab>mytabname</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>590</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <mygroupname translate="label">
                    <label>My Group Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <pdf_directory translate="label">
                            <label>PDF directory</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>
                                <![CDATA[relative path in the magento directory]]>
                            </comment>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </pdf_directory>
                        <sqs_endpoint translate="label">
                            <label>AWS SQS endpoint</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>
                                <![CDATA[can be found in the AWS SQS console]]>
                            </comment>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sqs_endpoint>
                    </fields>
                </mygroupname>
            </groups>
        </mycompany_sectionname>
    </sections>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModuleName/etc/config.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModuleName>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModuleName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mycompany_mymodulename>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModuleName_Block</class>
            </mycompany_mymodulename>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mycompany_mymodulename>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModuleName_Helper</class>
            </mycompany_mymodulename>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mycompany_mymodulename>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModuleName_Model</class>
            </mycompany_mymodulename>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <myCronjobName>
                <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mycompany_mymodulename/observer::work</model></run>
            </myCronjobName>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModuleName/etc/adminhtml.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mycompany_sectionname>
                                        <title>Section Title</title>
                                    </mycompany_sectionname>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the change visible, it is necessary to logout of the Admin area, and to login again.

This is, because the ACL are only loaded once on login, and we are obviously adding ACL here.

Thanks to my colleague, who pointed this out!