# 404 error at the configuration page

Tags: admin, extensions, configuration, 404

Each time I install new extension, and open the admin - system - configuration - module options I get 404 error.

Logging out and in helps, but  how to avoid this? The issue has something to do with the admin permissions cache, but how to refresh it programmatically, say, from the install script?

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46982/243

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior occurs because Magento caches the ACL in the admin user's session.  Here's the relevant line from [`Mage_Admin_Model_Session::login()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php#L127):

```
$this->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
```

You can have the ACL cache reloaded ("refreshed") by using the following code:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setReloadAclFlag(true);
$session->refreshAcl();
```